# How to click on a same button multiple times using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried searching for this but had 0 luck with this.
Here's my problem, on my webpage I have a button that at every click generates some data. I'm trying to automate this so Selenium could keep clicking on it for, say 50 times, after every 2 seconds and I can verify that the data is being generated correctly. How do I formulate my for loop to achieve this. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: At a guess, your page is being modified every time the button is clicked.  You'll have to move the `button = findElement(By)` inside of the loop, so that the reference is refreshed each time through.  Showing what code you've attempted so far, and the resulting exceptions, would enable us to better answer your question.

Comment: I have not written any code around clicking the button multiple times. So far I only have it clicking once using 
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath).click();

Answer (score 10):

Here's a sample:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
 //click the button
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath).click();
 //wait 2 seconds
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  //check that data is being generated correctly
  ...
}
```